# How to Get array of string from Native Code(C++) in Managed Code(C#)

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

is there any way through which we can get the collection of string from c++ to c#

C# Code

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
private static extern List<string> GetCollection();
public static List<string> ReturnCollection()
{
    return GetCollection();
}
```

C++ Code

```
std::vector<string> GetCollection()
{
std::vector<string> collect;
return collect;
}
```

The code above is only for sample, the main aim is to get collection in C# from C++, and help would be appreciated

//Jame S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a multitude of ways to tackle this, but they are all rather more complex than what you currently have.

Probably the easiest way to pass a string allocated in C++ to C# is as a `BSTR`. That allows you to allocate the string down in your C++ and let the C# code deallocate it. This is the biggest challenge you face and marshalling as `BSTR` solves it trivially.

Since you want a list of strings you could change to marshalling it as an array of `BSTR`. That's one way, it's probably the route I would take, but there are many other approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to convert that to something more C# friendly, like C-style array of `char` or `wchar_t` C-style strings.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874551/stdstring-in-c) you can find an example of `std::string` marshaling.  And [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d52c0ca8-71cf-40f5-a956-cda935d5805d) you'll find a discussion on how to marshal an `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use instead

C# part

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
private static extern void GetCollection(ref string[] array, uint size);
```

C++ part

```
void GetCollection(string * array , uint size)
```

and fill array in GetCollection function

Comment: That't won't work. Think about who allocates and deallocates the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change it to array and then marshal it. Marshalling arrays is much easier in PInvoke and in fact I do not believe C++ classes classes can be marshalled at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would return a SAFEARRAY of BSTR in C++, and marshal it as an array of strings in C#. You can see how to use safearray of BSTR here [How to build a SAFEARRAY of pointers to VARIANTs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796118/how-to-build-a-safearray-of-pointers-to-variants), or here http://www.roblocher.com/whitepapers/oletypes.aspx.